# calculating the Laplacian and Eigenvalues/vectors from tree graphs

Tags: tree, graph-algorithm, adjacency-matrix, eigenvalue, eigenvector

**Background:** I am currently developing topology search algorithms for ANNs (primarily inspired by the NEAT algorithm's augmentation operations). I have recently uncovered the bitter sweet adjacency matrix as a sparse representation of graphs which is seemingly very useful for finding cycles and sensible partitions within graphs using vectorized operations.

**My question:** does there exist a *memory efficient* algorithm to perform spectral graph operations such as calculating the *Laplacian* and *Eigenvalues/vectors* with a tree graph representation.

**Current Workaround:** The only way I can see to do this is to walk the tree and build an intermediate adjacency matrix for the calculation then attribute the results back to the nodes/edges. This still takes nodes^2 space though. Any suggested research topics or solutions would be greatly appreciated.